# Buttons on MainActivity do not register click when it(Main Activity) extends a BaseActivity with Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, button

I have a Base Activity which sets up Navigation drawer. My Main activity extends this `BaseActivtity`. The navigation drawer works perfectly fine but when I add any buttons on Main Activity, the `onClick` of the button doesn't get called.

Here is the Base Activity.

```
private void addDrawerItems(){
    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_list));
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


protected void onCreateDrawer() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarBase);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_drawer);

    addDrawerItems();
    setUpDrawer();


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}


private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id){
        selectItem(position);
        Intent intent;
        if (position==getResources().getInteger(R.integer.uploadPos)){
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UploadActivity.class);
        }
        else if (position == getResources().getInteger(R.integer.homePos)) {
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        }
        else if (position == getResources().getInteger(R.integer.browsePos)){
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BrowseActivity.class);
        }
        else if (position == getResources().getInteger(R.integer.myUploadsPos)){
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyUploads.class);
        }
        else if (position == getResources().getInteger(R.integer.logoutPos)){

            // destroying user session in the shared preferences table
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.preferences_table_name), 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.remove("UserID");
            editor.commit();

            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        }
        else {
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

**The MainActivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{
private String LOG_TAG = "Main Activity";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    checkForLogin();

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "on click test button");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "test toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }
    });
    button.bringToFront();
    super.onCreateDrawer();

}
```

I can see the button but, on clicking it, the toast doesn't show up when I click it.
If instead of extending `BaseActivity`, I extend `AppCompatActivity` (and remove `super.onCreateDrawer`), the toast works.

I tried bringing the button to the front with `button.bringToFront()`, that didn't work either.

The `NavigationDrawer` somehow is interfering with the clicks on `MainActivity` and I can't figure it out.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

**activity_base.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarBase"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_base" />
```

**content_base.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.nikhil.lecturenotessharing.BaseActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_base">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test"
    android:id="@+id/test_button"
    />
```

Please ask if more information or any XML layouts are needed.

Comment: What if u move `super.onCreateDrawer` above `setContentView`

Comment: past your layout file here, its likely another view is stealing the clicks on the button

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE All the changes done to the layout in BaseActivity(which include setting up the navigation drawer) would be lost, as the layout and the changes will be overwritten by the    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base)

Comment: You're calling `setContentView()` twice, the second time being in the `onCreateDrawer()` method, which you call after you've set the `Button`'s `OnClickListener`. When the layout is loaded the second time, the `Button` is a new instance which does not have the `OnClickListener` set on it.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you. That fixed it.I saw that it was being executed twice, but thought they would get executed sequentially and that it wouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: Whenever you call `setContentView()`, it completely replaces the `Activity`'s layout, and all the previous initialization you've done is lost. If each of your extended classes are going to have their own main content, you want to inflate that yourself into the `content_frame` `FrameLayout` in your `DrawerLayout`, instead of calling `setContentView()` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);` from `onCreateDrawer()`, it will works.

Because what you've initialized in `onCreate()` of `MainActivity.class` will be removed by calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);` in `onCreateDrawer()` of `BaseActivity.class`.

Keep in touch @nikhil vavs

Comment: Can you explain the flow a little more?  Isn't     `super.onCreateDrawer` executed completely before returning? The first `setContentView` should have been redundant.

Comment: @nikhilvavs Yeah, the first `setContentView` is redundant. But the initialization of your button is totally based on the first.When `setContentView` is invoked again, that button which has been initialized will not exist anymore.